# Splitting a vector into values

Tags: c++, performance, c++11

Say I have a vector of values from a tokenizing function, `tokenize()`. I know it  will only have two values. I want to store the first value in `a` and the second in `b`. In Python, I would do:

```python
a, b = string.split(' ')
```

I could do it as such in an ugly way:

```cpp
vector<string> tokens = tokenize(string);
string a = tokens[0];
string b = tokens[1];
```

But that requires two extra lines of code, an extra variable, and less readability.

How would I do such a thing in C++ in a clean and efficient way?

**EDIT:** I must emphasize that efficiency is very important. Too many answers don't satisfy this. This includes modifying [my tokenization function](https://gist.github.com/CrazyPython/be933ac13243f4db9c2a6155c63ae9b2).

**EDIT 2**: I am using C++11 for reasons outside of my control and I also cannot use Boost.

Comment: you do it the C++ way and iterate instead of tokenize

Comment: If the world really is rainbows and butterflies, and you "know it will only have two values", then why are you using a function that returns a container generally used for of an arbitrary-length result set? Declare your two `std::string` objects, pass them to some`tokenize_pair()` function that does just that (gets a pair of strings) as reference out parameters, and call it good.

Comment: @WhozCraig I don't know how to implement such a function. I come from a Python background. Such a function would be very useful.

Comment: So the tokenize function was written by somebody else?

Comment: @Fibbles It's two lines of code. You could say, but it's in the same file.

Comment: It requires the "extra" variable either way. It has to go someplace. Just because python is taking care of the creation of the extra space in the background doesn't magically remove the need. Python is still creating the extra variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you "know it will only have two values", you could write something like:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <tuple>

std::pair<std::string, std::string> tokenize(const std::string &text)
{
  const auto pos(text.find(' '));
  assert(pos != std::string::npos);

  return {text.substr(0, pos), text.substr(pos + 1)};
}
```

your [code](https://gist.github.com/CrazyPython/7850ff18e447ffbaf336520eb1e92c30) is a great example of the power of STL but it's probably a bit slower.

```
int main()
{
  std::string a, b;

  std::tie(a, b) = tokenize("first second");

  std::cout << a << " " << b << '\n';
}
```

Unfortunately without [structured bindings](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0144r2.pdf) (C++17) you have to use the `std::tie` hack and the variables `a` and `b` have to exist.

Comment: Much faster than @asimes answer and so for my code. Have an upvote, and I'll see if anyone can beat you before accepting... ;)

Comment: @uoɥʇʎPʎzɐɹC, It is faster than your implementation because his `tokenize` function is efficient. I didn't write a `tokenize` function, I showed how to assign two variables at once from a function

Comment: Whether `-O0` or `-O3` (although both are much faster with `-O3`), your code is 6-7 times as fast

Comment: @uoɥʇʎPʎzɐɹC, I responded here because you said that it is faster than my implementation but I did not implement anything. It is faster than your implementation

Comment: For people who use manila's implementation, don't forget to inline tokenize if you wish.

Answer (score 3):

With structured bindings (definitely will be in C++17), you'd be able to write something like:

```
auto [a,b] = as_tuple<2>(tokenize(str));
```

where `as_tuple<N>` is some to-be-declared function that converts a `vector<string>` to a `tuple<string, string, ... N times ...>`, probably throwing if the sizes don't match. You can't destructure a `std::vector` since it's size isn't known at compile time. This will necessarily do extra moves of the `string` so you're losing some efficiency in order to gain some code clarity. Maybe that's ok.

Or maybe you write a `tokenize<N>` that returns a `tuple<string, string, ... N times ...>` directly, avoiding the extra move. In that case:

```
auto [a, b] = tokenize<2>(str);
```

is great.

---

Before C++17, what you have is what you can do. But just make your variables references:

```
std::vector<std::string> tokens = tokenize(str);
std::string& a = tokens[0];
std::string& b = tokens[1];
```

Yeah, it's a couple extra lines of code. That's not the end of the world. It's easy to understand.

Comment: Could you help me implement a `tokenize_pair()` function that splits a string  into spaces? I don't need any other delimiters and performance is *key*.

Comment: I've been here long enough. Your answer simply does't answer the question in any way. You went for beauty instead of performance.

Comment: @uoɥʇʎPʎzɐɹC Your question was about beauty - you want to destructure and tokenize in one line. And I'm telling you that you will be able to do that in C++17 with structured bindings, not until then - there's no C++11 language facility to do both declare and destructure (`tie()` requires already-declared variables, which need to be default constructed).

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you'd rewrite the `tokenize()` function so that it returns a pair of strings rather than a vector:

```
std::pair<std::string, std::string> tokenize(const std::string& str);
```

Or you would pass two references to empty strings to the function as parameters.

```
void tokenize(const std::string& str, std::string& result_1, std::string& result_2);
```

If you have no control over the tokenize function the best you can do is move the strings out of the vector in an optimal way.

```
std::vector<std::string> tokens = tokenize(str);
std::string a = std::move(tokens.first());
std::string b = std::move(tokens.last());
```